# Как обработать POST запрос сервером на си

Tags: c, сервер

В кратце суть такая вот есть мой сервачок в него я отправляю через терминал вот такого содержания cURL: `curl --data "filename=test" http://localhost:5000` и получаю от прослушивания тело собственно POST запроса, а вот тело сообщение немного не улавливаю каким образом я могу получить??? и как быть к примеру если хочу передать не просто строку, а сам файл??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
printf("%s\n","Welcome to this server");

int listenfd = 0;
int connfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

char sendBuff[1024];

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

listen(listenfd, 10);

int n=0;
char recvBuff[1024];
char* result;
while(1)
{
connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

if( (n = read(connfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
{
result = recvBuff;
recvBuff[n] = 0;
if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
{
printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
}
}

close(connfd);
sleep(1);
}

return 0;
}
```

Вот что выдаёт терминал после того как я повторяю запрос дважды, то есть во второй раз всплывает переданная строка, но как её в коде отсечь сразу я чот недопонимаю, объясните или киньте на нужную литературу, будьте добры))

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

filename=testPOST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: не очень понятно, к чему именно относится вопрос, к `curl`'у или к серверу, и в чём именно проблема...

Comment: Ну я хочу чтобы сервер получил тело сообщения этого запроса, с курлом тут все прозрачно, сервер читает только тело запроса, но я не знаю как прочитать тело сообщения запроса. Как мне получить так называемый string_request??? Я показал, что сообщение само появляется в терминале, если запрос повторить. Инными словами я хочу обработать этот запрос сервером своим.

Comment: тело и так приходит... просто висит в буфере stdout'а... просто добавь `fflush(stdout)` после `puts`'а;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша терминология не соответствует действительности и сбивает с толку.

В HTTP есть 2 сущности:

- **заголовки** запроса/ответа (request/respose headers)
- **тело** запроса/ответа (request/response body).

Насколько я понял, у вас получается напечатать заголовки запроса, а вот тело (строчка `filename=test`) не печатается сразу, а только после второго запроса.

Происходит это из-за того, что вывод в консоль буферезированный. Соответственно, после окончания обработки запроса (после строки `close(connfd);`), вам надо сбросить буфер вывода. Для этого просто добавьте строчку `printf('\n');`

Comment: Вы почти решили мою проблему, но этот вариант позволит мне вывести тело запроса в терминал, а мне нужно обработать его на стороне сервера, то есть как я могу это тело записать к примеру в char*, чтобы работать с ним на стороне сервера???

Comment: Задал тупой вопрос, проверил отладку, там всё внутри, видимо проблема с лишним \r\n поставили меня в тупик, спасибо за помощь.